# Move 3d points to new coordinate

Tags: c++, opencv

help me please to move 3d points to new position.

I have 4x4 matrices.

```
M0: [1, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 1, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 1, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 1]

M1: [0.9999562539097905, 0.008249984275389101, -0.004407723466222909, 0.005836810275100765;
 -0.006668826208016603, 0.2983898553029519, -0.954420777754388, -0.05828274519526999;
 -0.006558736441276655, 0.9544084199187157, 0.2984318196247756, -0.0419597832901101;
 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

M0 is origin, M1 depends on origin.

And so on...

Then:

```
cv::Mat P0{ cv::Mat_< double >( 4, 1 ) << 0,0,0,1 };
cv::Mat p3d0{ M0 * P0 };
cv::Mat p3d1{ M1 * P0 };
...
```

I want to move all these 3d points to new coordinate P{X,Y,Z,1}

And finally i want to get new M0', M1'... moved to P.

**How to change origin of all matrices?**

Something like this:

```
M0'=X*M0;
M1'=X*M1;
...
```

How can i do it with OpenCV and c++?

I can summ only translation vector of each matrix with P.
For M0 it will work, but for other matrices, angles(rotation vector) should be changed too and i think changing only translation vector is not enough.

Here i go deeper to explain my problem:

I have computed pose coordinates of my cameras, presented as 4x4 matricies with origin in camera0 (M0):

[image]

So center(origin) of that system is in cam0. I want move this camera system to other origin.

Best regards, Viktor.

Comment: What is an N matrix, please? (Is that just a typo, or does it mean something?)

Comment: have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Linear_maps

Comment: @Micka Thank you, but that does not seem to interpret the phrase "4x4 N matrices." Did I miss something?

Comment: Fixed the text.

Comment: in the wiki text set n=4 and m=4 to get the formula for a 4x4 matrix multiplied with a 1x4 vector (your point).

Comment: `cv::Mat p3d0 = M0 * P0;` should work and `cv::Mat p3d1 = M1 * P0;` should also work. What's the problem? If your input point is 3D [0,0,0] only the translation is applied. What do you expect instead?

Comment: How to move(transform) M1 to P?

Comment: not sure what you mean by that. P is a point, how do you want to move matrix to a point? If you want to calculate the transformation that performs M1 and afterwards move additional P, you can do `M2 = [1,0,0,Px; 0,1,0,Py; 0,0,1,Pz; 0,0,0,1] * M1` where now M2 is the new transformation that combines the M1 transformation, followed by Translation by P

Comment: M0 is origin of camera system. I want change origin of that system. I have new origin point. What should i do to move camera system to new origin in this given point.

Comment: `T = P - (M0*[0,0,0,1])` and then use `MT = [1,0,0,Tx; 0,1,0,Ty; 0,0,1,Tz; 0,0,0,1]` and then `M1 = MT * M0`

Comment: So there is only translation? No rotation will perform for my task? Angles will not changed?

Comment: And then translation values belongs/depends on global origin and rotation values belongs/depends on local origin? Am i right?

Comment: it is the combination of both transformations, If you transform a direction (a vector with 4th dimension 0) you should see the same resulting direction for M0 and M1. But since M0 has no rotation, M1 wont have a rotation either. Maybe for me it is still not clear what you want to achieve. Once you said you want to move M1 to P, then you want to change M0 to a point (P?).

Comment: I want to move whole system to new origin. Old origin equal cam0 origin. And it is not clear for me will digits in 3x3 part of each matrix changes or they will be same as before translation.

Comment: what do you mean by `system`? I think what you man by `system` is a pose (for example of a camera) within a given coordinate system? Then it's easy: If TC is the transformation to change from your current coordinate system (e.g. from [1,0,0,0; 0,1,0,0; 0,0,1,0; 0,0,0,1] to the new coordinate system [...]) then your poses P1, P2, P3, ... are transformed by TC * P1, ... . Have a look at "base-change-matrix" to find/calculate TC.

Comment: System i mean math model/camera rig with origin coordinates in world.

Comment: So rotation performs around each camera local origin and translation relays global origin? If i translate camera system to new origin, rotation values should changes or not? As i see they not. But it is not clear for me.

Comment: My system is 6 pose matrices. Physically it is camera rig, but in code it is 6 4x4 matrices. And i move it in code. And the question is should be change translation vector only in each matrix or other values too?

Comment: So the final question: rotation 3x3 of each matrix depends on translation of camera in world? Should 3x3 values of each matrix changes when we moves camera rig in 3d space?

Comment: if your coordinate system change has a rotation included then your 3x3 part will change. If your coordinate system change does not have a rotation, then my pure translation formula will work and no 3x3 entry will change.

Comment: It is very important that you read and understand articles about affine transformation in 3d space using 4x4 matrices. If this doesn't help, please add a minimal and reproducible code example that exactly shows where you got stuck! As a new contributor it may be helpful to read [ask].

Comment: Thank you for help. You gave me conviction that when we shift system cameras angles does not change.